# PHP mail form isn't carrying variables values

Tags: php

I have a PHP code to capture variables off of my html form and send me an email.
For some reason this isn't working.

```
<?php

$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$subject = "My subject";
$email = $_POST["email"];
$headers = "From:" . $email;
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];


mail('myemail@mydomain.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

It sends an email, but it doesn't carry any of the variables.IE: it shows an empty FROM)

Comment: Well, you called it `$mensagem` but it should be `$message`. Or vice-versa. Also, try putting a space after the colon in `From:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-write this part of your code. you might find something

```
if(Isset($_POST["mensagem"]) && $_POST["mensagem"] != "")
$mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];
else
$mensagem ="Message body is empty";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variables are probably empty.

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if they're set or not.

---

**EDIT**: Oh, I didn't read your code carefully. Your `$message` variable is not defined...
Replace `$message` in the `mail()` function with `$mensagem` (if that variable carries a message body).

Answer (score 0):

If the header isn't in the valid format, it will be rejected.

The most reliable format is: `From: Person Name <email@example.com>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain about this `variable ? :<br> $mensagem<br>`
And `$message` is not defined, maybe its a little mistake in here.

And use space after from and check it again.